# Signature disappears when inserting documents to template

Tags: templates, docusignapi, document, signature

I'm trying to insert a word document into a Docusign template. The document inserts properly, but in addition to the two signers set up in the code, one of the signers that was on the template stays. Also, the second signature field is removed. Is there a setting that I'm missing? Here's my code:

```
             List<TemplateRole> roleslist = new List<TemplateRole>();

            TemplateRole InternalSignerRole = new TemplateRole();                                         // Set the Template Roles for the Internal Signer
            InternalSignerRole.Email = _currentDocInfo.sInternalSignerEmail;
            InternalSignerRole.Name = _currentDocInfo.sInternalSignerName;
            InternalSignerRole.RoleName = "SignerInternal";

            roleslist.Add(InternalSignerRole);                                                            // add to Template Roles list

            TemplateRole ExternalSignerRole = new TemplateRole();                                         // Set the Template Roles for the External Signer
            ExternalSignerRole.Email = _currentDocInfo.sExternalSignerEmail;                              //Create Template Roles for ExternalSigner
            ExternalSignerRole.Name = _currentDocInfo.sExternalSignerEmail;
            ExternalSignerRole.RoleName = "SignerExternal";

            roleslist.Add(ExternalSignerRole);        

            var apiClient = new ApiClient(conn.Base_URL);
            DocuSign.eSign.Client.Configuration.Default.ApiClient = apiClient;

            DocuSign.eSign.Client.Configuration.Default.AddDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authHeader);

            string accountId = null;

            // login call is available in the authentication api 
            var authApi = new AuthenticationApi();
            var loginInfo = authApi.Login();

            // parse the first account ID that is returned (user might belong to multiple accounts)
            accountId = loginInfo.LoginAccounts[0].AccountId;

            var baseUrl = loginInfo.LoginAccounts[0].BaseUrl;
            var separator = new string[] { "/restapi" };
            var basePath = baseUrl.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.None)[0] + "/restapi";
            apiClient = new ApiClient(basePath);

            EnvelopeDefinition envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition();
            envDef.EmailSubject = emailSubject;
            envDef.EmailBlurb = emailBody;

            //add custom fields you sent over with the document
            envDef.CustomFields = letterCustomFields;
            // Add a document to the envelope
            envDef.Documents = letterDocs;

            // Add a recipient to sign the document
            envDef.TemplateRoles = roleslist;
            envDef.TemplateId = "478d85c2-dc7c-4a89-a985-7d7a9101e36a";
```

Comment: I don't see documentId in here, does it match?
Also, does the roleName and Name match exactly to what's on the template?
The documentId and recipientId must match to what's on the tabs object in the template

Comment: You are using the old/legacy authentication header. Please consider moving to OAuth. I highly recommend this,

Comment: The documentID I'm using is 1. Here's the section of code I forgot to include;  
               'letter.FileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(_currentDocInfo.lsCompletedFile);
            letter.DocumentId = "1";
            docsToSend.Add(letter);
            letterCompTemplate.Document = letter;'

Comment: and is "1" the documentId reference for these signatures that disappeared?

Comment: Well, that document appeared and replaced the one that existed on the template. The document that I put in there had the same texts that were used for the anchor tags that were set up in Docusign on the template. Does there need to be some reference to that document in the TemplateRoles that i set up?

Comment: yes, tags belong to recipients. Recipients in templates, if you want to be able to customize them, would have a roleName. I do see you have a roleName, but does it match the template's?

Comment: You are mixing two things, it seems you want to apply template "478d85c2-dc7c-4a89-a985-7d7a9101e36a" on letterDocs, is this correct assumption? or do you want envelope to have document from template and letterDocs?

Answer (score 0):

First off, please don't use legacy authentication. That is old, not as secure and should not be used in new code that you're building.
Note that tabs (signature elements) are associated with both a recipient (a specific one) as well as a document (a specific one).
If you are trying to replace a document in a template, when creating an envelope from it (which is what you're doing, you're not replacing the document in the template, but rather in the envelope you create), you need to ensure the tabs refer to the same document and same recipient (based on the role).
Also, another recommendation is to use composite templates, which provide more flexibility for such scenarios. See [excellent blog post by Gil Vincent](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-why-use-composite-templates) for more information.